# PySide2 setStyle not applying to QTabBar

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

For some reason when I apply run `setStyleSheet` to a parent widget or to the QApplication instance, `setStyle` no longer works on `QTabBar`.

Here's a reproduction:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class _Style(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    pass


application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
widget.setStyleSheet("QLabel { color: green; }")  # <-- Remove this line and it works
widget.tabBar().setStyle(_Style(parent=widget.tabBar()))
print('Is the custom style', isinstance(widget.tabBar().style(), _Style))

widget.show()

application.exec_()
```

If you run the code above, "Is the custom style" reports `False`
If you comment out or remove `widget.setStyleSheet("QLabel { color: green; }")` and re-run it, "Is the custom style" reports `True`.

[According to Qt's QStyle documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QStyle.html):

`A style can also be set on an individual widget using the setStyle() function.`

When setStyleSheet is called, on either `widget` **or** `application`, `widget.tabBar().style()` is replaced with `QCommonStyle`. The intended class, `_Style`, gets completely unset.

How can I fix this so that "Is the custom style" reports True, even if a parent widget changes its style sheet?

Note:

Tested with PySide2-5.15.2.1 on both CentOS 7 and Windows 10

Comment: Whenever a style sheet is set on a parent widget (or the QApplication!), the widget syle becomes an overridden (and ***private***) QStyleSheetStyle based on the parent/widget style set for that parent or widget, including **all** its child widgets. That style gets *complete* control over the underlying style and there is absolutely **nothing** you can do about it: style sheets *override* the style, but due to their implementation you cannot control their behavior, not even with `setStyle()`. The real question here is: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's interesting that you say that because I was able to get something kind of working as long as I wasn't using QTabWidget and I ran setStyleSheet on the parent widget. I'll try to make a repro for that later.

Comment: > The real question here is: what are you trying to achieve?

I'm trying to make QTabWidget's / QTabBar's individual tab text more controllable. I need to be able to, given a Tab index, set index 0 to bold, index 1 to not bold etc.  There's a forum post on this topic already: https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2018-April/029734.html

And I discovered this issue while integrating it into a larger project.

Answer (score 0):

From [setStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.setStyle),

> Qt style sheets are currently not supported for custom QStyle subclasses. We plan to address this in some future release.

so it doesn't work like that.

But considering your goal, I guess this script could help you.

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

sheet = """

QLabel {
  color: green;
}

QTabBar > QLabel{
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
}


QTabBar::tab:selected{
    background-color: orange;
}
QTabBar::tab:!selected{
    background-color:dodgerblue;
}

QTabBar > QLabel[failed="true"] {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
"""


class CustomTabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def addTab(self, widget, title, warning=False):
        index = super().addTab(widget, "")
        piece = QtWidgets.QLabel(text=title, parent=self.tabBar())
        piece.setProperty("failed", True) if warning else ...

        self.tabBar().setTabButton(index, QtWidgets.QTabBar.LeftSide, piece)

        return index


application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

widget = CustomTabWidget()

widget.setStyleSheet(sheet)


widget.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello, for test1"), "test1")
widget.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello, for test2"), "test2")
widget.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello, for test3"), "test3")
test4 = widget.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello, for test4"), "test4", True)
print(test4)

widget.show()

application.exec_()
```

You can refer stylesheet guide [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/stylesheet-examples.html#qt-style-sheets-examples). And use dynamic properties to target that label in tab.

Though, it's not possible to target a tab at some index, so use a widget inside the tab and then change its properties.